# Create PGFPlots Histogram from file

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How can I create a histogram from a file as follows. I can't seem to pick up the variable names from the file even.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
0,70.1
20,10
40,5.5
60,3.3
80,2.2
100,1.
120,1.
140,0.9
160,0.7
180,0.6
200,0.4
220,0.3
240,0.3
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar interval]
\addplot table [x, y, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I want the histogram to display the first column on the `xaxis` with the percentages on the `yaxis` and have whatever amount of bins are in the file (i.e. amount of rows).

Comment: what do you mean by 'mark the height'? Do you want a line plotted there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I understand your question:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
0,70.1
20,10
40,5.5
60,3.3
80,2.2
100,1.0
120,1.0
140,0.9
160,0.7
180,0.6
200,0.4
220,0.3
240,0.3
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[ybar,fill] table [x, y, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\addplot[domain=0:240] {70.1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Results in [image]

Comment: I just edited the question to remove that red herring there. I can't seem get the output you have in your example. If I remove the `\addplot[domain=0:240] {70.1};` line, the xaxis and yaxis ranges are from 1 to 5. It looks more like a bar chart. Do I have another version of pgfplots or something?

Comment: any errors? Have you sanitized your data file (it had some errors in it) ?

Comment: @user2146441 instead of `[ybar,fill]` use `[ycomb]` to get a histogram instead of a bar plot.

Comment: This works fine but is not a histogram yet. How can I put the bars flush with the yaxis and no space between like a histogram? For example, the first point (0,70.1) shouldn't have a bar at 0 on the xaxis, it should be a bar placed between 0 and 20 (in fact, the bar should be the point (0-20, 70)). How can I do this?

Comment: you can use the option you provided in the beginning: `ybar interval` instead of `ybar`